# 2015 Honda accord

Tags: honda, accord, water-leak

I live in Hannibal MO and we have had heavy rains for a few days. I opened my trunk today to add my groceries and water ran down from the trunk lid. A few hrs later I went back to shopping and began to add items to the back seat area of the car and there is water stains still very wet around the seat belts connections.  Is there suppose to be a water seal between the rear window and the roof?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!